# Mat-dialog box was not displaying on opening in angular. It is displaying only on loading the entire page

Tags: angular

on opening the dialog box, data was not displaying
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVvTM.png)

And it should open like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cshbv.png)

Component.ts:

```
openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogBoxComponent, {
        maxWidth: '40%',
        // hasBackdrop: false,
        panelClass: 'my-custom-dialog-class'
    });
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res) => {
        if (res) {
            this.userService.addUserTeamMember(res).subscribe(
                (res: any) => {
                    this.getTeamUsers();
                    this.alertService.success(res['message']);
                }, error => {
                    console.error(error);
                    this.alertService.danger(error['message']);
                }
            );
        }
    });
}
```

component.html:

```
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()" 
class="btn btn-primary ">Add member</button>
```

dialog.component.html:

```
<div class="mat-dialog-container ">

<form [formGroup]="dataform">

    <mat-form-field class="col-12">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="name" class="toolbar-search" 
      placeholder="Enter Name" type="text" id="name" matInput
               required
               [readonly]="data">
    </mat-form-field>
<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button mat-button mat-dialog-close class="btn btn- 
       danger">cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-2" 
      [disabled]="dataform.invalid" [mat-dialog- 
       close]="dataform.value">
            {{data ? 'Updated' : 'Add Member'}}
        </button>
</form>
</div>
```

dialog.component.ts:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUSUU.png)

Comment: Check if your component used in dialog is added in `entryComponents` of your module.

Comment: check your console.log for errors. This looks like a case of an error happening when the page was loading.  Also, you may want to post the code that you are using to generate this page

Comment: yes, i have added DialogBoxComponent to entryComponents.

Comment: can you post the template (.html) file as well?

Comment: We actually need to see the DialogBoxComponent.ts (or js) and DialogBoxComponent.html

Comment: As Dj Burb, looks like you has an error (in Angular when an error happens stop render the component). Perhafs you try to show the form and there're no form yet -use `<form *ngIf="myform" [form]="myform>..</form>` to avoid initial errors or some similar. Check the console using F12 to see if an error happens

Comment: We need the DialogBoxComponent.ts or DialogBoxComponent.js to see if you have valid objects in your template.  For example, we need to know what dataform is

Comment: @Bhargavi : Please share screenshot of the dev console. without it, I am not sure about providing  a concrete answer.  Do you have the `FormsModule` imported ?

Comment: @ shashank vivek , i have imported FormsModule and in console no errors was found.